# Nullpointer exception when iterating over a list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have an ArrayList of User objects.

```
private ArrayList<User> users;
```

This is the constructor of the class which contains the array list "users" :

```
public CommunicationThread(Socket socket, ArrayList<User> users) {
    super("CommunicationThread");

    try {
        // Initialize data fields 
        this.users = users;

        System.out.println("Client connected : " + client_socket.getInetAddress().toString());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not initialize communication properly. -- CommunicationThread.\n");
        e.printStackTrace(client_out); // Also inform the client.
    }
}
```

I wrote a procedure "search_user" which searches for the user given a username.

```
private User search_user(String username) {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.users.size(); i++) {
        User found_user = this.users.get(i);
        if(found_user.username.equals(username))
            return found_user;
    }       
    return new UserNotFound();
}
```

When I'm trying to search a user it always gives me a nullpointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "CommunicationThread"
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DirectoryService.CommunicationThread.search_user(CommunicationThread.java:92)
```

The "users" list is empty when I'm searching, but this should simply return a new "UserNotFound" object and is not supposed to throw a nullpointer exception.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` can be thrown by several parts: `this.user` is `null`, `found_user` is `null`, `found_user.username` is `null`. Do the proper debug to find which of these variables is `null`.

Comment: I will also suggest doing the reverse on the equality check... `username.equals(found_user.username)` and in top of that, do a nullability check on `found_user` or (preferred) make sure the list does not have `null` values...

Comment: The nullpointer exception is thrown by `this.users.size()` , is this because the ArrayList is empty? I would expect it to return 0 instead of null...

Comment: *The nullpointer exception is thrown by `this.users.size()`, is this because the `ArrayList` is empty?* No, it is because `this.users` **is `NULL`**.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you're right! The problem came from the fact I initialized "users" to the given array list in the constructor, but the given arraylist was never initialized before, so I thought "users" was initialized but in fact it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using a different constructor to create an object of your `CommunicationThread`. Instead doing useless `null` checks and uglyfy your code, I recommend initialize your list when declaring the field:

```
public CommunicationThread {
     //updated declaration of users to interface List
     private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
     //rest of the code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple do a null check and return your "UserNotFound" immediately.

Tip: Write a log statement to check null status of your list object.

```
private User search_user(String username) {
    if(this.users == null || this.users.size() == 0){
        return new UserNotFound();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < this.users.size(); i++) {
        User found_user = this.users.get(i);
        if(found_user.username.equals(username))
            return found_user;
    }       
    return new UserNotFound();
}
```

This is a very simple fix. Try to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

`UserNotFound` is returned when you're searching for a user that's not there, but what you're doing is an assignment to an uninitialized list (it happens before you're calling "search").

Search the code that calls `CommunicationThread` constructor and see that you're passing a `null` value as `ArrayList<User> users`.

*Solution*: on declaration of `private ArrayList<User> users;` initialize it to an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether users is null first:

```
private User search_user(String username) {
    if(users == null){
        return new UserNotFound(); 
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < this.users.size(); i++) {
        User found_user = this.users.get(i);
        if(found_user.username.equals(username))
            return found_user;
    }       
    return new UserNotFound();
}
```